# Подбор названия улицы по совпадению

Tags: android, ios

Пишу приложение (android/ios), в котором пользователю предлагается ввести название улицы, например, в г.Новосибирск. Необходимо чтобы при вводе, допустим, некоторого количества символов, ему предлагалось выбрать из списка совпадений...

Вопрос в следующем - существуют ли уже где-то собранные воедино названия улиц или же бесплатные сервисы... или же единственным решением является создание вручную массивов из названий улиц для каждого города внутри приложения? :()

ps. Прошу прощения заранее - не уверен, какие правильные метки можно выставить для данного вопроса.

Comment: Распарсьте openstreetmaps, или может попробовать "позаимствовать" данные у Яндекса и Гугля - их GeoIP в разумной мне бесплатен

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: не относится к программированию. хотя из темы вопроса кажется, что он по программированию, на самом деле автор просит подсказать, где взять базу данных с названиями улиц

Comment: *КЛАДР* и *ФИАС* Вам в помощь.

Comment: Используй Yandex.Geocoder. Абсолютно бесплатная штука

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать AutoCompleteTextView

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
 "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
 };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Но если городов много, то список городов лучше получать из какого-то внешнего источника. При изменении текста в  вашем 'AutoCompleteTextView' получать список городов которые начинаются на введенный текст и обновлять адаптер.